# os.walk with multiple loops for json files

Tags: python, json, loops, os.walk

The directory tree looks like this:
[image: Tree]

My goal is to enter the member ID and the program should analyze the associated files (activities.json) from all days and write all these activities into an Excel file.

When I use wb.SaveAs it removes the previous activities and replaces them with the activities from the next JSON file , that means at the end I have just the activities from the last json file.

I do not know whether this is due to the **loops** used or from **wb.SaveAs**

NB: if I minimize the code more than that, it becomes incomprehensible
My Code:

```
rootDir = 'C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/Linkedin/linkedin_hb_ma'
x = 0
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    if dirName.endswith("1Xb95ebb-d87d-4a4c-X4-XX1"):
        for file in fileList:
            abs_path = os.path.join(dirName, file)
            if file.endswith("activities.json"):
                json_data = json.loads(open(abs_path).read())
                rows = []
                for record in json_data ["activities"]:
                    if (json_data ["activities"][x]["action"]["name"].startswith("liked")):
                        action = json_data["activities"][x]["action"]["name"]
                        target = json_data ["activities"][x]["action"]["target"]
                        rows.append([action,target]) 
                        ExcelApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
                        ExcelApp.Visible = True
                        wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add()
                        ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
                        header_labels = ('action','target')
                        for indx, val in enumerate(header_labels):
                            ws.Cells(1, indx + 1).Value = val
                        # insert Records
                        row_tracker = 1
                        row_tracker = row_tracker + 1
                        column_size = len(header_labels)
                        for row in rows:
                            ws.Range(
                                ws.Cells(row_tracker, 1),
                                ws.Cells(row_tracker, column_size)
                            ).value = row
                            row_tracker += 1
                        wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'ouutput3.xlsx'), 51)
                        wb.Close(False)
                        ExcelApp.Quit()
                        ExcelApp = None
            x=x+1
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: Collect all the results into a list. Then save the whole list to the excel file at the end, not each time through the loop.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: @Jasmijn I described it above. I hope you have an idea

Comment: You save all Excel files under the same path/name: `wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'ouutput3.xlsx')`. So, either change the name for each new json-file from which you extract data, or open the Excel file outside the loops, add a new worksheet for each new relevant json-file and store the data there, and save it at the end, again outside the loops.